# Is it possible to init yarn berry over a proxy?

Tags: proxy, yarnpkg, yarnpkg-v2

Recently I've upgraded my node version to **16.15.1**. Before the node upgrade I used a 1.x yarn version. Now I want to use `yarn v3.2.x` in my project.

Normally this would be achieved by executing the command `yarn init -2` in the console. This would generate a `.yarn/releases` folder in my project where the `yarn-[version].cjs` is stored. Furthermore, in the project `.yarnrc.yml` the line `yarnPath: .yarn/releases/yarn-[version].cjs` is added.

However, I have the problem that I work in a closed working environment. When I execute the command `yarn init -2` I get problems with the proxy.

This is the error I get:

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/raw/master/packages/yarnpkg-cli/bin/yarn.js: connect ECONNREFUSED xxx.x".
```

I tried to set the proxy in the project and also in the user `.yarnrc.yml` but both didn't seem to work.

My question is whether there is a possibility to add a proxy url to the `yarn init -2` command, e.g. via a cmd flag?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can specify a proxy to use during installation. Add [`httpProxy`](https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc#httpProxy) or [`httpsProxy`](https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc#httpsProxy) to `yarnrc.yml`.